# How can I adjust line width for individual lines in a combined plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

When I adjust line width for this type of plot it works.

```
plot(x1,y1, 'm','Linewidth',1)
hold on
plot(x2,y2, 'b','Linewidth',2)
hold on
plot(x3,y3, 'r','Linewidth',3)
hold on
plot(x4,y4, 'c','Linewidth',4)
hold on
plot(x5,y5, 'o','Linewidth',5)
```

But not when I do this.

```
plot(x1, y1, 'm','Linewidth',1,x2, y2, 'b','Linewidth',2,x3, y3, 'r','Linewidth',3,x4, y4, 'c','Linewidth',4,x5, y5, 'o','Linewidth',5);
```

I get an error.

Is it possible to adjust line width for a combined plot?

Comment: In the first code block, you don't need to call `hold on` 4 times. Just one time is enough (after the first plot command). The second code block is valid in Octave only

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to adjust line width for a combined plot?

No (well yes but not in a cleaner way).

You can adjust the parameters for all of them together if you want a single line. If you want control over the appearance of each of them, you will need to do separate plots.

You can do it accessing the properties, but I suspect that is just longer and less clear, so not sure if it is really the right solution.

```
h=plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, ...);
h(1).LineWidth=1;
h(2).LineWidth=2;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternate approach that is more scalable for greater numbers of plots and/or extra properties uses `arrayfun`. Basically, if you set up the data for all your plots in arrays, you can then plot all data with only one line of code

```matlab
% set up the data and all plot attributes
x = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5};
y = {y1, y2, y3, y4, y5};
styles = ['m', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'o'];
widths = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

% setup figure
figure
ax = axes('NextPlot','add'); % like calling hold on
% plot all elements
% equivalent to a for loop: for i = 1:length(x)
arrayfun(@(i) plot(ax, x{i}, y{i}, styles(i), 'linewidth', widths(i)), 1:length(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using hold since it is hard to know if it is on or off when you do the next plot.  I like to use plot for the first line and line for subsequent lines like this:

```
plot(x1, y1, 'm', 'linewidth', 1)
line(x2, y2, 'color', 'b', 'linewidth', 2)
line(x3, y3, 'color', 'r', 'linewidth', 3)
line(x4, y4, 'color', 'c', 'linewidth', 4)
line(x5, y5, 'color', 'o', 'linewidth', 5)
```